# check for user logged in before going to scene in storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, authentication, uistoryboard

First, I am using storyboards for my navigation. I have come to a point where I am at a menu screen that goes off to 4 different views (just with a navigation controller) for 2 of those views I want it to check if the user has logged in and if not I want the LoginViewController/View brought up. I am very new to objective c/xcode and after searching for a solution this is what i have come up with. I do not know how to tie this in to my program. Does this just need to be linked to my button or am i completely off with what i am doing now?

```
if (self.appDelegate.userHasActiveLogin) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];}
else {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just a tip if you haven't discovered this already, the stanford course on ios development on itunes u: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016
It really speeds up the process of learning ios development, the lectures are excellent

Comment: Update your original question you asked ~2 hours ago instead of creating a new one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708904/verifying-login-before-loading-view-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to create manual segues in your storyboard.

Ctrl-drag from your menu controller (orange symbol) to the child controller, select push. Click on the segue and give it an identifier in the attributes inspector. Now you can check if user is logged in and then conditionally call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logged in segue" sender:self];` in your menu's VC.

The condition is that all the VCs must be in the same storyboard, but I suspect that is the case.